# General way to own a value (don't specify `Rc` or `Box`)

Tags: rust, ownership

Is there a enum/trait for owned values in general, for when you don't want to specify *how* exactly the value is owned (either shared or not), but you just want to own it.
I need to store references to closures in a struct, which means that they have to live as long as the struct lives. I can't copy them, of course, so they need to be references. But I don't want to make restrictions, so the user of the struct should be able to choose how they want to transfer the ownership.
This is a general problem when you can't copy the values or if they are really big.

Very general example, what I am looking for is this `Owned<T>`

```
struct Holder<T> {
    value: Owned<T>,
}

...

let rc = Rc::new(variable);
let holder = Holder::new(rc.clone());
let holder2 = Holder::new(Box::new(variable2));
```

An example for a very easy "implementation" of this type would be:

```
enum Owned<T> {
     Unique(Box<T>),
     Shared(Rc<T>),
}
```

I hope I could explain what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be a bit tripped up by the word "owns", which is understandable in Rust! Every value is owned by something, but sometimes the value *refers to* something that you don't own.

In your case, you just need to accept a `T`. Then `Holder` will own the `T`:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Holder<T> {
    value: T,
}

impl<T> Holder<T> {
    fn new(v: T) -> Holder<T> {
        Holder { value: v }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let variable = "Hello world".to_owned();
    let variable2 = "Hello moon".to_owned();

    let rc = Rc::new(variable);
    let holder = Holder::new(rc.clone());
    let holder2 = Holder::new(Box::new(variable2));
}
```

Even if you pass a reference to `Holder`, it will own *the reference*. It will not own the referred-to item however.

Comment: Wait - how is it possible that you can pass a `Box<T>` or `Rc<T>` to the function when it expects a `T`? They are different types and we don't have implicit conversion in Rust! I tested it however, and it compiles! http://is.gd/Pwo5hu

Comment: @Kapichu: You are getting tripped by your use of `T`, so let's rewrite this `impl <U> Holder<U> { value: U, }`. If `U` can be any type, it can be `T`, `Box<T>`, `Rc<T>` or `Vec<T>`, cannot it?

Comment: So I can safely assume that I can use a `Box<T>` or `Rc<T>` just like a `T`?

Comment: @Kapichu yep! As written, `Holder` places no restrictions on the type it accepts.

Comment: Hm, but now the Holder can't do much with the value, in my case the value is a function, so it has to implement `FnMut`, which is not the case for `Box` or `Rc`

Comment: Wouldn't `DerefMut<Target = FnMut>` be my solution? When ever I need to call the function, I simply dereference. `Box` and `Rc` et al should implement those.

Comment: @Kapichu in general, that sounds right. However, `Rc` is for immutable data, so it wouldn't work. However, it sounds like you are straying from your original question (general ownership of a value), so you may want to ask another, more specific question to get more eyes on it.