# General pointer type for `Rc`, `Box`, `Arc`

Tags: rust

I have a `struct` which references a value (because it is `?Sized` or very big). This value has to live with the struct, of course.
However, the struct shouldn't restrict the user on *how* to accomplish that. Whether the user wraps the value in a `Box` or `Rc` or makes it `'static`, the value just has to survive with the struct. Using named lifetimes would be complicated because the reference will be moved around and may outlive our `struct`. What I am looking for is a general pointer type (if it exists / can exist).

**How can the struct make sure the referenced value lives as long as the struct lives, without specifying how?**

Example ([is.gd/Is9Av6](http://is.gd/Is9Av6)):

```
type CallBack = Fn(f32) -> f32;

struct Caller {
    call_back: Box<CallBack>,
}

impl Caller {
    fn new(call_back: Box<CallBack>) -> Caller {
        Caller {call_back: call_back}
    }

    fn call(&self, x: f32) -> f32 {
        (self.call_back)(x)
    }
}

let caller = {
    // func goes out of scope
    let func = |x| 2.0 * x; 
    Caller {call_back: Box::new(func)}
};

// func survives because it is referenced through a `Box` in `caller`
let y = caller.call(1.0);
assert_eq!(y, 2.0);
```

Compiles, all good. But if we don't want to use a `Box` as a pointer to our function (one can call `Box` a pointer, right?), but something else, like `Rc`, this wont be possible, since `Caller` restricts the pointer to be a `Box`.

```
let caller = {
    // function is used by `Caller` and `main()` => shared resource
    // solution: `Rc`
    let func = Rc::new(|x| 2.0 * x); 
    let caller = Caller {call_back: func.clone()}; // ERROR Rc != Box

    // we also want to use func now
    let y = func(3.0);

    caller
};

// func survives because it is referenced through a `Box` in `caller`
let y = caller.call(1.0);
assert_eq!(y, 2.0);
```

([is.gd/qUkAvZ](http://is.gd/qUkAvZ))

Possible solution: `Deref`? (http://is.gd/mmY6QC)

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::ops::Deref;

type CallBack = Fn(f32) -> f32;

struct Caller<T>
        where T: Deref<Target = Box<CallBack>> {
    call_back: T,
}

impl<T> Caller<T> 
        where T: Deref<Target = Box<CallBack>> {
    fn new(call_back: T) -> Caller<T> {
        Caller {call_back: call_back}
    }

    fn call(&self, x: f32) -> f32 {
        (*self.call_back)(x)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let caller = {
        // function is used by `Caller` and `main()` => shared resource
        // solution: `Rc`
        let func_obj = Box::new(|x: f32| 2.0 * x) as Box<CallBack>;
        let func = Rc::new(func_obj); 
        let caller = Caller::new(func.clone());

        // we also want to use func now
        let y = func(3.0);

        caller
    };

    // func survives because it is referenced through a `Box` in `caller`
    let y = caller.call(1.0);
    assert_eq!(y, 2.0);
}
```

Is this the way to go with Rust? Using `Deref`? It works at least.

Am I missing something obvious?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31215418/2979958) did not solve my problem, since the value is practically unusable as a `T`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `Deref` provides the necessary functionality, [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) and [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) are more appropriate for this situation (`Borrow` more so than `AsRef` in the case of a struct). Both of these traits let your users use `Box<T>`, `Rc<T>` and `Arc<T>`, and `Borrow` also lets them use `&T` and `T`. Your `Caller` struct could be written like this:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

struct Caller<CB: Borrow<Callback>> {
    callback: CB,
}
```

Then, when you want to use the `callback` field, you need to call the `borrow()` (or `as_ref()`) method:

```
impl<CB> Caller<CB> 
    where CB: Borrow<Callback>
{
    fn new(callback: CB) -> Caller<CB> {
        Caller { callback: callback }
    }

    fn call(&self, x: f32) -> f32 {
        (self.callback.borrow())(x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It crashes with the current stable compiler (1.1), but not with beta or nightly (just use your last Playpen link and change the "Channel" setting at the top).  I believe that support for `Rc<Trait>` was only *partial* in 1.1; there were some changes that didn't make it in time.  This is probably *why* your code doesn't work.

To address the question of using `Deref` for this... if dereferencing the pointer is all you need... sure.  It's really just a question of whether or not the trait(s) you've chosen support the operations you need.  If yes, great.

As an aside, you can always write a new trait that expresses the *exact* semantics you need, and implement that for existing types.  From what you've said, it doesn't seem necessary in this case.

Comment: I did an edit with a workaround for that, I just wrapped the value in a Box again. Still, is using `Deref` *the* solution for that?

Comment: I've expanded the answer.  I really should have addressed that in the first place (I think I got distracted by solving the immediate problem)