# How do I write generic code that accepts either a trait or a smart pointer to the trait (Box, Rc, etc)?

Tags: generics, rust, smart-pointers

I am writing a discrete event simulator that simulates processes, exchanging events. Processes are implementations of the trait process, and are stored in the simulation class, which tells them when to process events.

A simulation can contain processes of only one type, or it can contain processes of different types. This is why I need a freedom to be able to choose dynamic processes.

I currently do it with boxes. Every code that uses the simulation needs to create boxes and put their created objects in boxes.

```rust
trait Process {
    // methods
    fn start();
    fn process_event();
}

struct Simulation {
    processes: Vec<dyn Process>
}

impl Simulation {
    fn add_process(&mut self, p: Box<dyn Process>) {
        processes.push(p);
    }
    
    fn run() {
        // calls process_event on processes, based on simulation logic
    }
}
```

My biggest problem, is that in some cases these processes need to have self-references. Then I need to replace box with either Pin or OwningRef, and I don't want to have every possible simulation, creating a Pin or OwningRef. So, i would want some kind of generic parameter to tell simulation to use different classes for boxes.

A nice extension would be to be able to not have dynamic dispatch at all, and have simulation contain actual process types, not generics.

So, i want something like - `Simulation<P> where P is either a Process or Deref<Process>`.

Comment: You can't accept "either a `Process` type or a `Deref<Target: Process>` type" because these are not mutually exclusive: you can implement both `Process` and `Deref<Target: Process>` for the same type, in which case the behavior of the code would be ambiguous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General pointer type for \`Rc\`, \`Box\`, \`Arc\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229841/general-pointer-type-for-rc-box-arc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both variants of generic `Simulation` are possible.

1. Containing smart pointers to processes ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=96721c2ea57a1256dc2d53f7307cc15d)):

```
trait Process {}
struct P {}
impl Process for P {}

struct Simulation<T: std::ops::Deref<Target = dyn Process> + Sized> {
    processes: Vec<T>
}

impl<T: std::ops::Deref<Target = dyn Process> + Sized> Simulation<T> {
    fn add_process(&mut self, p: T) {
        self.processes.push(p);
    }
    
    fn run(&self) {
        // calls process_event on processes, based on simulation logic
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s: Simulation<Box<dyn Process>> = Simulation { processes: vec![] };
    s.add_process(Box::new(P {}));
    s.run();
    
    let mut s: Simulation<std::rc::Rc<dyn Process>> = Simulation { processes: vec![] };
    s.add_process(std::rc::Rc::new(P {}));
    s.run();
}
```

2. Containing actual process types ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=09da1501524cff4006085f08bdf1bb5c)):

```
trait Process {}
struct P {}
impl Process for P {}

struct P2 {}
impl Process for P2 {}

struct Simulation<T: Process> {
    processes: Vec<T>
}

impl<T: Process> Simulation<T> {
    fn add_process(&mut self, p: T) {
        self.processes.push(p);
    }
    
    fn run(&self) {
        // calls process_event on processes, based on simulation logic
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s: Simulation<P> = Simulation { processes: vec![] };
    s.add_process(P {});
    s.run();
    
    let mut s: Simulation<P2> = Simulation { processes: vec![] };
    s.add_process(P2 {});
    s.run();
}
```

3. You can even have one type of Simulation, containing different types of processes ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=841c64b6bcfac0df5e90e24b387c7b29)):

```
trait Process {}
struct P {}
impl Process for P {}

struct P2 {}
impl Process for P2 {}

struct Simulation {
    processes: Vec<Box<dyn Process>>
}

impl Simulation {
    fn add_process<T: Process + 'static>(&mut self, p: T) {
        self.processes.push(Box::new(p));
    }
    
    fn run(&self) {
        // calls process_event on processes, based on simulation logic
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s: Simulation = Simulation { processes: vec![] };
    s.add_process(P {});
    s.run();
    
    let mut s: Simulation = Simulation { processes: vec![] };
    s.add_process(P2 {});
    s.run();
}
```

Comment: i want to have one type that can be either of those things. alternatively a type that allows to wrap any smart pointer to process into a process.