# What are the best practices for implementing generic code that can be reused over different types of ownership: &'a T, or Box<T>, or A: T?

Tags: rust

I have a trait `T`. I am implementing a struct `S` that owns or keeps a reference to an object that implements trait `T`. It can be done in one of a few ways:

1. ```
   struct S<A: T> {
       field: A,
   }
   ```
2. ```
   struct S<A: T, 'a> {
       field: &'a A,
   }
   ```
3. ```
   struct S<'a> {
       field: &'a T,
   }
   ```
4. ```
   struct S {
       field: Box<T>,
   }
   ```

... and so on.

In different contexts, different ownership models might be useful.

I would like to implement `S` in such a way that it could be created in any of the following ways:

```
trait T { }
struct A { }
impl T for A { }

fn main() {
    let a = A {};
    let s1 = S::new_owning(a);
    let s2 = S::new_from_ref(&a);
    let s3 = S::new_from_trait_ref(&a as &T);
    let s4 = S::new_from_boxed_trait(Box::new(a));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a bit case dependent, but when possible, you should prefer taking the value directly (as in, some `T: Trait`).

There is a similar API guideline ([C-RW-VALUE](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#c-rw-value)), which advises interfaces to take a parameter `T` directly, rather than a mutable reference to a value which implements `std::io::Read` or `std::io::Write`. This works because `Read` and `Write` are also implemented for mutable references to arbitrary `T` types implementing these traits.

If you are in control of that trait, following the same approach is quite idiomatic and addresses your concern without the need for so many constructor functions.

```
trait T { }
// generic implementations for references and smart container types follow
impl<'a, U: ?Sized + T> T for &'a U { }
impl<U: ?Sized + T> T for Box<U> { }

struct A { }
impl T for A { }

fn main() {
    let a = A {};
    let s1 = S::new(a);
    let s2 = S::new(&a);
    let s3 = S::new(&a as &T);
    let s4 = S::new(Box::new(a));
}
```

See also:

- [General way to own a value (don't specify `Rc` or `Box`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31215418/1233251)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer and for the link to the API guidelines — it's a good read.

Do I understand correctly, that if I add `impl<'a, U: ?Sized + T> T for &'a U { }`, then I won't need to explicitly add the lifetime parameter to the definition of `S`?

Comment: One further question: if such derived trait implementations for &'a U and Box<U> are useful, why aren't they automatically produced by the compiler? Are there any downsides except for compilation time?

Comment: @OlegEterevsky From `S` point of view, it will accept any type parameter as long as it implements the trait. When that type has a lifetime, the compiler will keep track of it.

Comment: @OlegEterevsky Not all traits should have an inheriting behaviour on reference types. For example, this is the case for traits with consuming methods (taking self by value).